# Orchestration tool for docker containers

Tags: nginx, docker, load-balancing, consul, orchestration

Which is the best open source orchestration tool for docker containers ? As i already tried Nginx,Electric cloud, docker swarm. As far as i know Nginx only provides load balancing.Although Electric cloud has end to end deployment facility but it's not open source. Consul can do monitoring and service discovery part. Is there any tool which can provide load balancing,service discovery,high availability all together ? or if it is possible to use 2/3 tools all together to accomplish all of the requirements, i can go for it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also look at:

- [Kubernetes](http://kubernetes.io)
- [OpenShift](https://www.openshift.org)

OpenShift is the more complete solution here, using Kubernetes internally, but adding extra layers on top for better security, routing, automated builds and deployments.

You can try out OpenShift in a hosted environment at:

- https://www.openshift.com

You can though also install OpenShift Origin yourself to your own systems if want to self manage it.

Answer (score 0):

[Rancher](http://rancher.com/) can do all of those things. It is basically a complete ecosystem for running Docker. Rancher also their own image/Compose catalog with a really sharp UI.

You should also check out the changes in Docker 1.12 with regards to Swarm becoming [Swam Mode](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/).

New Features in 1.12:

- Cluster management
- Service scaling
- Load balancing
- Rolling updates (blue/green deploys)
- Built in TLS
- Support for [Docker Services](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/swarm-tutorial/deploy-service/)

This writeup explains the updates in more detail:

[Docker Swarm Is Dead. Long Live Docker Swarm.](https://www.infoq.com/news/2016/06/dockercon-docker-swarm)